# Applying TRIM() in Pig for all fields in a tuple

Tags: apache-pig

I am loading a CSV file with 56 fields. I want to apply TRIM() function in Pig for all fields in the tuple.

I tried:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TRIM(*);
```

But it fails with below error-

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045:   Could not infer the matching
>   function for org.apache.pig.builtin.TRIM as multiple or none of them
>   fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can't use TRIM function like that. Can you paste some sample inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

To Trim a tuple in the Pig, you should create a UDF. Register the UDF and apply the UDF with `Foreach` statement to the field of the tuple you want to trim. Below is the code for trimming the tuple with UDF.

```
public class StrTrim extends EvalFunc<String> {
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try {
            String str = (String)input.get(0);
            return str.trim();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```