# PIG TRIM and UPPER

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, trim, uppercase, udf

I am new to Hadoop programming, looking for help in pig. I have data coming from `simple.txt` format as `,` delimeter. I have two use cases. I want to do `ltrim(rtrim())` on all the columns and turn to `UPPER` for selected fields.

Here is my script:

```
party = Load '/party_test_pig.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(....);
Trim_party = FOREACH Upper_party GENERATE TRIM(*);
Upper_party = FOREACH party GENERATE UPPER(col1), UPPER(col2), UPPER(col3);
```

`Upper_party:`After making it uppercase, I want to view all the columns and not only columns that get change to upper case.

`Trim_party:`did some research and found out, to trim all columns I will have to write an UDF. I can do `Trim_party = FOREACH Upper_party GENERATE TRIM(col1)...TRIM(coln);` but I feel this is not an efficient way and time-consuming.

Is there any other way, I could make this script work without writing UDF for Trim?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it woulf be easier if you give a sample of your data. From what I understand, I would do this way :

```
-- Load each line as one string with TextLoader
A = LOAD '/user/guest/Pig/20151112.PigTest.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:CHARARRAY);
-- Apply TRIM and UPPER transformation, it will keep spaces that are inside your strings
B = FOREACH A GENERATE UPPER(line) AS lineUP;
-- Split lines with your delimiter
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(lineUP, ',')) AS (col1:CHARARRAY, ... ,coln:CHARARRAY);
-- Select the columns you need
D = FOREACH C GENERATE TRIM(col1) AS col1T, ..., TRIM(coln) AS colnT;
```

Comment: hi @AntonyBrd thank you for the answer. Upper worked properly. But Trim didn't work.

Comment: I even ran `B = FOREACH A GENERATE TRIM(line) AS lineTRIM;` just to verify if it works but it failed here too.

Comment: RECORD 1:
`101,2015-11-11,201, hola ,Shah,Rukh,Khan, Shahrukh Khan ,SRK,Mr,Male,Married,Hindi,2065,1965-11-02,2065-11-02,1992-11-02,2065-11-02,100`

RECORD 2:
`102,2015-11-12,202, hi ,Kajol,Tanuja,Mukerjee, Kajol Devgan ,KD,Mrs,Female,Married,Hindi,2066,196-11-03,2065-11-03,1992-11-03,2065-11-03,101`

Comment: it failed with an error or it failed to do what you had expected ? If so, what did you expect ?

Comment: it failed to what I expected... so my input was  ##Shahrukh Khan## . Consider ## as space which I would like to TRIM in my final output. The expected ouput is Shahrukh Khan (left and right space should be removed).

Comment: Input: `101,2015-11-11,201, hola ,Shah,Rukh,Khan, Shahrukh Khan ,SRK,Mr,Male,Married,Hindi,2065,1965-11-02,2065-11-02,1992-11-02,2065-11-02,100`. As you can see in 8th column there is an extra space after comma. So I want to get rid of that space.

Expected: `101,2015-11-11,201, hola ,Shah,Rukh,Khan,Shahrukh Khan,SRK,Mr,Male,Married,Hindi,2065,1965-11-02,2065-11-02,1992-11-02,2065-11-02,100`

Comment: OK the reason is actualy quite simple, my bad ! If we apply TRIM to the whole line it wont affect each field. I changed my code. Sorry.

Comment: so I have TRIM each and every column ? 
`D = FOREACH C GENERATE TRIM(col1) AS col1T, TRIM(col2) AS col2T, TRIM(col3) AS col3T, TRIM(col4) AS col4T;`
What if I have 200 columns ?

Comment: Yes, you have to TRIM each field. If you have 200 columns, I suggest to remove all spaces :     A2 = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,' '','');     If you don't want to remove all spaces, make a UDF that takes a tuple of 200 elements and return an other tupple of 200 elements.

Comment: I think UDF will be a better option.. coz what happenes by replacing is if there is a space between name `Shahrukh Khan` then it becomes `ShahrukhKhan`. Thanks @AntonyBrd

Comment: Hi @AntonyBrd I wrote the pig udf from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413674/applying-trim-in-pig-for-all-fields-in-a-tuple). I want to apply to all fields now so what shud be my `FOREACH` statement. `trim = FOREACH xyz GENERATE package_name.class_name(??);`

Comment: Hi @LazyBones, you will first havo to register your jar in your pig script, then you must define your function : `REGISTER /path/to/jar/myJar.jar;` and `DEFINE STRTRIM packagename.classname();`   But I dont think the UDF you wrote will give the result you expect. You should trim each value of your tuple and not only the first one (I suggest to use a lambda expression or something like that instead of a for loop)